# installation and disk partition

Tags: installation

When I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop some questions were asked regarding drives(i think so). What do they mean?

***ntfs***

***/dev/sda/***

***/dev/sda1/***

/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give more information to get a better answer.

You need to identify what you're trying to do. Are you installing Ubuntu alongside of Windows or other operating systems? If so, your objective is slightly more difficult. If you're just trying to replace your whole hard drive with Ubuntu, then you're on the easy track.

/dev/sda is usually the device file of the main hard drive on your computer.

Your disk can have one or more partitions. /dev/sda1 is the first partition on your hard drive. You're most likely going to want to install the root of your Ubuntu installation on /dev/sda1 if you're using the whole hard drive for Ubuntu. Otherwise you'll want to partition your drive up and install Ubuntu on a different partition.

ntfs is a type of filesystem often used by Windows.

Please give more information regarding your question or it will be marked as too vague.